Weird error in mail client (evolution)
I use Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular) on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 (Gen12) with the standard Gnome shell (see here for my setup). The problem is not specific to oracular, it was present with 22.04 as well.
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7d02 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Graphics] (rev 08)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d03 (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e4d (rev 20)
00:06.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7eca (rev 10)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 7e4c (rev 20)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d0d (rev 01)
00:0b.0 Processing accelerators: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake NPU (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7e7f (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e70 (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e73 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e38 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e03 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation NVMe SSD Controller XG8 (rev 01)
49:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller (2) I225-LMvP (rev 03)

I am getting this weird error where after a restart, the mail client evolution does not connect to any of my email accounts (I get errors about "Timeout reached" popping up in my client, see screenshot below). I say it is weird, because it only happens sometimes and when I restart the computer the problem is usually gone (it happens maybe 50% of the time when I restart - it is very annoying!).

I think this issue might have something to do with the gnome keyring (when I login, I get a a popup telling me to unlock the keyring with a password, which I can succesfully complete).
I have no idea how to diagnose this problem (i.e., which logfiles to look at etc), any help would be very much appreciated!
